# 2d double array to image

Tags: java, arrays, awt, simulation

I'm currently working on a simulation with continuous agents, which leave a pheromone trail on a 2d double array. The pheromone trails need to be on a 2d array because of a diffusion with a mean filter that needs to be performed. Ultimately, I need to visualise the agents and the pheromone trails, by transforming the double array directly into an `awt.Image`.

Comment: What is the range of values in the 2D double array?  You have red, green, and blue values that range from 0 through 255.  Create a BufferedImage with the same dimension as your 2D array, convert the 2D double values to a pixel color, and write the pixel color in the same position in the BufferedImage as the 2D array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically create a `BufferedImage`, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226853/2d-double-array-to-image#comment122356878_69226853) by [Gilbert Le Blanc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300257/gilbert-le-blanc) and use its `setRGB` method to set the pixels (or get its `Graphics` to draw on it).

Example, assuming values are between `0.0` and `1.0`, converting to gray:

```
private static BufferedImage create(double[][] array) {
    var image = new BufferedImage(array.length, array[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (var row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
            image.setRGB(col, row, doubleToRGB(array[row][col]));
        }
    }
    return image;
}

private static int doubleToRGB(double d) {
    var gray = (int) (d * 256);
    if (gray < 0) gray = 0;
    if (gray > 255) gray = 255;
    return 0x010101 * gray;
}
```

The `doubleToRGB` can be changed to use more *complicated* mapping from value to color.

Example red for lower values, blue for higher:

```
private static int doubleToRGB(double d) {
    float hue = (float) (d / 1.5);
    float saturation = 1;
    float brightness = 1;
    return Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, saturation, brightness);
}
```

<sub>Note: posted code is just to show the idea - can/must be optimized - missing error checking</sub>

<sup>Note 2: posted mapping to gray is not necessarily the best calculation regarding our perception</sup>